# Is there a way to configure PostFix to queue up emails sent to an address, merge all attachments into a zip file, and send it?

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I have a noisy app that spits out about 30 necessary emails per day. The recipients are indicating it crowds their inboxes and takes longer to consume than before. I cannot fix the app's rate of output. How might you go about setting up a CentOS+PostFix server to receive emails to a specific address and redistribute all emails in some interval (or on some time schedule) as one with a static body content and attachments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a mailing list software that is able to sent out digests instead. Sent mails to this lists and have users subscribe to them.